# onclick executes only the first function

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

What I need is that, when I press a button, it should execute 2 functions. However, only the first provided function is executed, even if I change the order. Both functions work separately, but not together. I need to do this in pure Javascript.

```html
    <input type ="text" list="novadi" id="gerboni">
      <datalist id="gerbonis">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
        <option value="3">
        <option value="4">
     </datalist>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" id="rainis" name="autors" value="1"> Rainis<br>
      <input type="radio" id="karlis" name="autors" value="2"> Baumaņu Kārlis<br>
      <input type="radio" id="caks" name="autors" value="3"> Aleksandrs Čaks
   </form>
    <input type="submit" value="iesniegt" onclick="funkcijas();">
    <script>
   
    function pirmaisotrais(){
   var a=document.getElementById("novadi");
   var b=document.getElementById("gerboni");
    if(a.value=="4"){
     document.write('1. pareizi <br>');
    }else if(a.value ==""){
     document.write("1. Jūs neievadijāt atbildi<br>")
    }
    else{
     document.write('1. nepareizi <br> pareizā atbilde : 4<br>');
    }
    if(b.value=="4" || b.value=="4."){
     document.write('2. pareizi <br>');
    }else if(b.value ==""){
     document.write("2. Jūs neievadijāt atbildi<br>")
    }
    else{
     document.write('2. nepareizi <br> pareizā atbilde : 4<br>');
    }
   
  }
  function tresais(){
   if (document.getElementById("rainis").checked) {
    document.write('3. nepareizi <br> pareizā atbilde : Baumaņu Kārlis<br>');
   }else if (document.getElementById("karlis").checked == true) {
     document.write('3. pareizi <br>');
   }else{
     document.write('3. nepareizi <br> pareizā atbilde : Baumaņu Kārlis<br>');
   }
   

  }
  function funkcijas(){
   pirmaisotrais();
   tresais();
   
   
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Share with us the HTML code too

Comment: What if you dont use document.write?

Comment: The functions are working alright.

Comment: Share your html code so we can know more where you are facing problems.

Comment: There is no "novadi" Id so it will result in breakage of code when you use a.value

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt there actually is a very similar HTML input as the first one that i provided with an id of novadi, i just didn't paste it because, the site gave me a message of having too much code, and not enough plain text

Comment: @Kalvis as I mentioned in my answer - don't use document.write, because it refreshes page. You can use alert or console.log for testing purposes

Comment: @PavelTřupek can you provide some other alternatives to alert and console.log? For example to make a new section in the same page, that contains the output of functions

Comment: @Kalvis added example to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use document.write, because it refreshes page as you can see in this example:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="btn1">
<input type="button" id="button2" value="btn2">
```

```
//btn1 calls both functions
let btn = document.getElementById("button1");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert('1'); });
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert('2'); });


//btn1 calls first function which refreshes page
let btn2 = document.getElementById("button2");
btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {document.write('1');});
btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {document.write('1');});
```

If you want to output something to your page, use innerHTML or innerText of some element:
Eg. you want to set text of existing element with id=result:

```
<div id="result">Result will be shown here</div>
```

```
//replace actual text
document.getElementById("result").innerText = "Replace results text with this.";

//append to actual text
document.getElementById("result").innerText += "And then append this";
```

Comment: Im sorry if i miss your point, as i am a newbie in Javascript, but i need only one button

Comment: @Kalvis I understand, I just wanted to show you, that document.write refreshes your page. If you want to output smth to your page, use innerHTML or something similar. You can replace `document.write` with `alert` in your code to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, i replaced document.write with console.log, and that seems to help

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that when a `submit` button is clicked, it causes the `form` element to fire its `submit` event and send all the form data to the specified URL in the form's `action` attribute and this means page navigation. So, if you are calling functions that attempt to modify the current page, you won't see those changes because you'll be navigating away from the current page.

But, to register event handlers, [don't use inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) (`onclick`) to set up your event handlers. Use modern standards of `.addEventListener()`.

```js
// Get reference to button
let btn = document.querySelector("input[type='button']");

// Set up first click handler
btn.addEventListener("click", foo1);

// Set up second click handler
btn.addEventListener("click", foo2);

function foo1(){ 
  console.log("Hello from foo1");
}

function foo2(){ 
  console.log("Hello from foo2");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="iesniegt">
```